# Abstracting out onClick actions

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to abstract out functionality of a simple app based in ReactJS, however the console is throwing up a few problems that I can't figure out.

It seems to revolve around my use of `this.setState(...)`

I have commented out the original functions in the main Class just for visibility.

**Button Class (will be moved to new file)**

```
class Button extends React.Component {

  buttonAction(props) {
    switch (this.props.type) {
      case 'add':
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          counter: prevState + this.props.label
        }));
        break;
      case 'take':
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          counter: prevState - this.props.label
        }));
        break;
      case 'reset':
        this.setState(() => ({
          counter: 0
        }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <button onClick={this.buttonAction(this.props.type)}>{this.props.label}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

**App class**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // initial state of counter
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  // // function to increment the counter
  // incrementCounter = (increment) => {
  //   this.setState((prevState) => ({
  //     counter: prevState.counter + 1
  //   }));
  // };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type={'add'} label={1}/> 
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

[Please see my code example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qlv5xo2v7)

Comment: Please post relevant code here, not just a link to it

Comment: I get told off for putting too much code, I get told off for not putting any... Can't win XD - Updated for you now @SterlingArcher

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `buttonAction` with the correct `this` context. You need to bind it to your component. Try adding this to your `Button` component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonAction = this.buttonAction.bind(this);
}
```

Edit:
The way of passing the event handler `buttonAction` is incorrect. This should be the correct way of doing it:

```
<button onClick={this.buttonAction}>{this.props.label}</button>
```

Comment: I would go with @Jules's example above - In some of the tutorials I have seen people say that using "bind(this)" is not technically correct :-/

Comment: what?)) this is a surprise to me, could you link those tutorials?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `bind(this)`, you can use arrow functions as an alternative but you're mistaken if you've been told it's not "technically correct"

Comment: could you explain the downvote? Anything wrong or harmful with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve by looking at an older piece of code I already had...

@Jules Dupont was on the right track in his first answer, moving functions into the App class.

However, I decided to refactor a few things and have ended up with the following:

```
// Class of button to click
class Button extends React.Component {

  // function to handle click
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.increment, this.props.type)
  };

  // what to render to virtual DOM
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.state}{this.props.increment}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

// Result output
const Result = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.counter}</div>
  );
};

// App class
class App extends React.Component {
  // initial state of counter
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  operators = {
    '+': function (a, b) { return a + b },
    '-': function (a, b) { return a - b },
    // ...
  }; 

  // function to increment the counter
  incrementCounter = (increment, type) => {
    console.log('hit')
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      counter: this.operators[type](prevState.counter,increment)
    }));
  };

  // what to render to virtual DOM
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Buttons of different incremental value */}
        <Button type={'+'} increment={1} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter} />
        <Button type={'-'} increment={1} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter} />

        {/* result that will be displayed */}
        <Result counter={this.state.counter} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```